# While bundling i'm getting this webpack error and i don't understand why it was coming in sharepoint spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online

While bundling the project i'm getting this error :
Error - [webpack] Error processing webpack stats: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJson')
Error - [webpack] Webpack error: TypeError: localizedPath.startsWith is not a function

And my versions are
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.17.1
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
+-- typescript@5.2.2
`-- yo@4.3.1
--npm @8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

What node version do you have installed?

Make sure you have v16.13+ installed for SPFX 1.17.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility

After doing this. Remove your node_modules folder and do npm install again.

Comment: Yes i have node v16.13.0 and sprfx 1.17.1 but then also it's coming error i tried 2-3 time to reinstall but then also this webpack issue was coming

Answer (score 0):

for some reason i got this error after installing `npm i @microsoft/sp-http` (same thing for @microsoft/sp-http-base) but i resolved it by installing version `@microsoft/sp-http@1.18.0` (@microsoft/sp-http-base@1.18.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had this suddenly occur in an existing project - I switched from one branch to another, and when I switched back, it was giving this error. After an hour of fighting with all kinds of things, I eventually just deleted the entire local folder, re-cloned from the repo, and it's building fine.